# eslint enforce indent, but ignore first level

Tags: javascript, eslint, babel-eslint

I wrap code in a block and I'd like eslint ignore first level of indentations. Is it possible?

There is a rule that can be used for function:

```
"indent": ["error", "tab", {"outerIIFEBody": 0}]
```

it would work with

```
(function(){
const myObject = {
  key: "value"
};
})();
```

But it doesn't work with a block:

```
//desired format:
{
const myObject = {
  key: "value"
};
}

//instead of this:
{
  const myObject = {
    key: "value"
  };
}
```